# How to make the standard change-of-variables in the plane-parallel radiative transfer equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, coordinate-systems

This is a basic technique used frequently in going from the general coordinate-free radiative transfer equation (RTE) to the RTE formulated for the plane-parallel atmosphere geometry (see Liou, Introduction to Atmospheric Radiation, 2002: Sec. 1.4.4), however I don't follow how it's done and the details are not provided (assumed 'obvious')

the general coordinate-free RTE can be written as a simple 1st order DE:

$$ \frac{dI(s)}{\gamma(s)ds} = -I(s) + J(s) \qquad (1)
$$

where the path is $s$, and a differential change along path = $ds$. I suppose it doesn't even really matter if you know what the rest of the individual terms mean, if you're just thinking in terms of solving a DE.

Now we want to go to a specific geometry, with vertical zenith = z, zenith angle = $\theta$, and azimuth angle = $\phi$.

So now restricting paths to be (radial) straight lines in the direction $s(\theta,\phi)$
I believe we can write

$ z(\theta) = s(\theta,\phi)\cos\theta $

so that
$ dz = ds\cos \theta \\
ds = dz/\cos\theta$

So now I substitute for $ds$ in (1) using above to get
$$ \cos\theta \frac{dI(s)}{\gamma(s)dz} = -I(s) + J(s) \qquad (2)
$$
Now we've gotten to my first point of confusion.  Here they will often simply re-write Eq. (2) (see Liou Eq. 1.4.10) as,
$$ \cos\theta \frac{dI(z;\theta,\phi)}{\gamma(z;\theta,\phi)dz} = -I(z;\theta,\phi) + J(z;\theta,\phi) \qquad (3)
$$

Is that legal, to simply replace the $s$ variable in all the function arguments with $z;\theta,\phi$ ??

Isn't it true that $ s(z(\theta)) $ (noting $z(\theta)$ is independent of $\phi$ in this geometry)? Then don't we need to substitute $s = z/\cos\theta $??

Now, the next step taken (and my second point of confusion) is they define

$ \mu = \cos \theta$

and then just re-write Eq. (3) as

$$ \mu \frac{dI(z;\mu,\phi)}{\gamma(z;\mu,\phi)dz} = -I(z;\mu,\phi) + J(z;\mu,\phi) \qquad (4)
$$
So again, can you just make that substitution in the function arguments $\theta \to \mu$?  What about $ \theta = \arccos \mu $??

Confusion Point #3:
From Eq. (4) we now introduce another new variable (the optical depth $\tau$) as
$$ \tau(z) = \int_z^{\infty} \gamma(z';\mu,\phi)dz' $$
which is measured downward with $\tau(\infty) = 0 $
so we have $ d\tau(z) =  -\gamma(z;\mu,\phi)dz $

(at least I think that's where the negative sign comes from...?)
and for the final hurrah, they now write [Liou, Eq. 1.4.22]
$$ \mu \frac{dI(\tau;\mu,\phi)}{d\tau} = -I(\tau;\mu,\phi) + J(\tau;\mu,\phi) \qquad (5)
$$
Based on my above confusion regarding the previous changes-of-vars made inside the function arguments, you get bet I'm baffled on how we 'clearly' (grrrrrr) go from $ z \to \tau $ inside the arguments!!

I guess all 3 of my 'confusion points' are related to how we generally do these change-of-variables inside functions, when we may not know the specific form of the functions involved (for instance $I(...)$ and $J(...)$ in above Eqns). Can someone please help me understand how this is done correctly?

Comment: The following 'test' may illustrate what's going on: Suppose $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$; what is $f(r,\theta)$? (The joke being that one can distinguish between mathematicians and physicists by how they answer.)

Comment: (hope it's correct to respond to your comment with a comment...) Ok, well I would start by letting $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$ and $\theta = \arctan (y/x)$, so I would conclude $f(r,\theta) = r^2 $

Comment: On further thought... I would start by letting $x = r\cos \theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ as usual, then substitute $f(r\cos \theta, r\sin\theta) = r^2 = f(r,\theta)$.  But in this case we know the form of the function $f(x,y)$ so the substitution can be explicitly carried out, which is not the case for functions $I(s), J(s)$ in above, and I'm beginning to think this is the crux of my confusion.

Comment: Well, my point is you'd be more likely to see $f(r,\theta)=r^2$ in a physics/engineering text rather than $f(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$; the conversion to polar would be understood implicitly, and it would moreover be an error to expect $f(r,\theta)=r^2+\theta^2$. Similarly, in writing $I(\mu)$ I imagine that the change-of-coordinates is understood implicitly e.g. if $I(s)=s$ then $I(z;\theta,\phi)=z(\theta)/\cos\theta$ and $I(z;\mu,\phi)=z(\mu)/\mu$. (Note that I've followed the same convention at the level of $z$ itself!)

Comment: I think I get your point, but let me try to rephrase and tell me if I'm on track. Since we don't actually know the explicit form of $I(z; \mu,\phi)$, when we go from Eq. (4) to Eq. (5) by simply substituting $z \to \tau$ and $d\tau = \gamma dz$, it is just assumed that all the correct change-of-var operations, substitutions, (weight-factors, Jacobians? etc), are made, and contained/included within the new $I(\tau,\mu, \phi)$ expression?

Comment: I'd say so, yes. Note, though, that while the later expressions are require care in interpretation, the initial expression in terms of $s$ can be understood directly. It thus provides a reference point, both in understanding what they mean and in confirming that any results they obtain are consistent with it.

Comment: Taking a specific case, to go from Eq. (3) to Eq. (4) by the change-of-vars $\mu = \cos \theta$ , it appears that a simple substitution $\theta \to \mu$ was made in the function arguments, but what is implied is that everywhere within the explicit function forms (whatever they may turn out to be) the change $\theta = \arccos \mu$ is made. E.g. if $I(z; \theta, \phi) = \frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}$ then $I(z; \mu, \phi) = \frac{\sin(\arccos\mu)}{\arccos\mu}$  Look OK?